# cambiar un valor de una propiedad css desde js

Tags: javascript, css

me gustaría cambiar una propiedad de una etiqueta css mediante js, el objetivo es cambiar el top y el left de una clase llamada "toast" para que se mueva al darle a un boton...

el css lo tengo así

```
.toast {
top: 35px !important;
}
```

ahora quiero que al darle a un boton o con un activador ejecute una funcion que cambie el "35px !important" por un 350px !important (el valor numerico será una variable que cambiará)

he probado con

```
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("toast");
            console.log(items);
             document.querySelector(".toast").style.top = "350";
            // document.querySelector(".toast").style.top = "350px !important";

            Materialize.toast('Cambios guardados.', 9000, 'rounded')
```

(el meterialize.toast es para que me aparezca un toast ya con la posicion cambiada)

Comment: Creo que necesitas indicar las unidades. en lugar de `"350"` prueba `"350px"`. Y toast necesita `position: absolute`

Comment: así es como lo tengo en la linea comentada y tampoco me funciona..

Comment: ¿Esos toast como los estas generando?  ¿Con materialize? ¿Y como los invocas? Pon el html o el javascript donde los llamas. Lo digo porque segun como, lo que estas haciendo, no esta actuando sobre nada, porque aun no estan generados en el DOM, y deberias hacerlo al generarlos. Ademas, veo que materialize permite el uso de clases distintas como opciones al llamar a los toast, y quizas deberias probar eso más bien.

Comment: lo estoy generando con  Materialize.toast('Cambios guardados.', 9000, 'rounded')

si cambia su posicion, ya que desde el css si cambio el 35 por 500 el toast aparece en otra posicion (al ser el cambio en el css, cuando se genera el toast, aparece con las propiedades que lee del css)

Comment: Quita el `!important` de tu CSS, y mira a ver si te funciona con `350px`. Creo que el `important` del CSS está cogiendo prioridad sobre el nuevo valor y entonces no cambia.

Comment: así lo he puesto
document.querySelector(".toast").style.top = "850px"; (quitado el !important del css)
y me salta este error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que más se puede acercar a lo que quieres es esto:

```javascript
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.newtoast { top: 350px !important; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        
Materialize.toast('Cambios guardados.', 9000, 'newtoast rounded')
```

Con esto definimos una nueva clase denominada `newtoast` que agregamos al `<head>` del documento y finalmente aplicamos en el `Materialize` conjuntamente con el estilo `rounded`.

Aquí puedes verlo en acción: https://jsfiddle.net/Lod1zueg/

Para el tema de como aplicar estilos he encontrado la información en la [documentación](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/dialogs.html) sobre la versión de Materialize que estás usando en tu código.